# Can affection be lost when the affection reward mechanism is triggered?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When the pokemon has sufficient hearts in the new affection mechanism in pokemon-amie, sometimes events such as surviving with 1HP occur during battle.

When this happens, one heart floats up and away from the pokemon.

Is this a "spending" of a "heart resource" that after a certain threshold would cause one heart to be lost in the pokemon-amie?

I've stopped petting/feeding/playing with that particular pokemon to find out but I can't conclude anything yet because I've not triggered the in-battle event many times.

Has anyone lost a heart in pokemon-amie? Is it possible to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you cannot lose affection that has been gained in Pokemon Amie. The heart floating away, that's your pokemon saying "I love you, I got this in the bag, I have the force of will to keep fighting for you!"

Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Like the answer above, it doesn't lose the affection heart from that.

It is, however, possible to lose affection. As far as I know, it is only possible to lose it if you trade a Pokemon that you originally got in a trade from one game back to the first.

Let's say you traded a Pokemon for something like a Fennekin, and you traded that Pokemon from your X game to your Y game. If you were to trade it back to X (or Y) it would lose its affection because it wasn't originally yours begin with.

I imagine it's also like this when you trade a Pokemon from X to Y (or Y to X). A maxed out affection Pikachu on your Y game would have zero hearts on X; because, it wasn't originally your X character's Pokemon. If you return it back to Y, it's affection would be restored, since, your Y character was the original owner.

Comment: So, the long story short is, affection isn't transferred when trading, but getting the same Pokemon BACK from trading, the game remembers its affection level

Comment: I believe @Robotnik 's summary is too narrow. It seems it only remembers the affection of it's OT when trading; I'm raising some pokemon my husband hatched for me (for the boosted XP) and when I loaned one back to him, it totally forgot me. Good thing I only had one heart thus far!